# How to manage files and dirs under WSH?

Tags: javascript, windows, scripting, wsh, file-management

Is it possible to manage files and directories (i.e. get a directory's content, create/copy/delete files, etc.) usig javascript in WSH ?
I did a quick look at MSDN and I cant find an object that let me do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkx696eh(VS.85).aspx) what you're looking for?

Comment: I see. However, that's not under the WSH section in the documentation. It doesn't seem to be part of the WSH DOM.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work. Just poining out that it's somewhere else in the MSDN documentation tree.

Comment: I'm looking at it in MSDN under "Microsoft Windows Script Technologies".

Comment: Yep. But I was looking under "Windows Script Host". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var fso = WScript.CreateObject("ScriptingFileSystemObject");
var CurDir = fs.GetFolder("C:\\temp");
var Files = CurDir.Files;
for(var fileitem = new Enumerator(Files); !fileitem.atEnd(); fileitem.moveNext())
{
   fso.CopyFile(fileitem.item(), ExeDir);
}
```

See [MSDN documentation on FSO.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: First line should be "Scripting.FileSystemObject" not "ScriptingFileSystemObject"